# JQuery Chosen, find and remove a value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a chosen multiple select in I want to remove a single tag(item) from the list, is there a way to do this dynamically let's say from another event?

Comment: Show code/ jsfiddle please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I found the way:

```
var dyn_var = val1;
$(".sel option[value='"+dyn_var+"']")
    .remove();

$(".sel")
    .trigger('chosen:updated');
```